# Is it possible to generate java classes from a Drools DMN file's custom data types?

Tags: java, drools, kie

I can't find a way to export the custom data types created in the VSCode DMN Editor into Java classes.

I see that you can go in the other direction and import Java classes, but there must be a way to go the other way around.  I would expect that Java classes could be created and added to the kjar so I can pick them up in my Java project when I add the kjar as a dependency.

My custom data types:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYNk8.png]

Comment: To what end? You can't write classes in your rules and then use them in your Java application. That is, I challenge the assertion of "there must be a way to go the other way around."

Comment: The KIE editor can create custom data types from Java classes. I am thinking from a generic java point of view.  If there is a class in a jar file and it is on the classpath, you can create instances of that class.  In the context of drools.  I would like the kjar to have the classes and then they would be available for me to use in my Java project because they would be on my classpath via maven dependencies.    It defeats the purpose of having .dmn IDEs if non programmers have to look at java classes as custom data types.

Comment: A jar is a zip file that contains compiled .class files. A kjar is a zip file that contains drl/dmn/xml/xlsx/etc files. DMN is not compiled to .class files. A kjar is not a jar.

Comment: Thanks!  That is good to know that a kjar isn't related to a jar.  Do you know the recommended way to inject facts that are based on custom data types in Java?

Comment: You mean, other than writing your models in Java?

Comment: Yes,  I have a Business Analyst and Subject Matter Experts who work on the DMN, and then I can take that and put it in a web service.

Comment: I popped open the kjar and if you put the java Beans for the custom data types the DMN project,  the classes show up in the kjar file. 
META-INF/kie/
META-INF/kie/ca.queensu/
META-INF/kie/ca.queensu/sror/
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/ca.queensu/
META-INF/maven/ca.queensu/sror/
ca/queensu/beans/sror/tAdjunct.class
ca/queensu/beans/sror/tCourse.class
ca/queensu/beans/sror/Activator.class
META-INF/agetest.dmn
META-INF/kmodule.xml
META-INF/sror test.dmn
META-INF/kie/ca.queensu/sror/drools-model
META-INF/maven/ca.queensu/sror/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/ca.queensu/sror/pom.properties

Comment: The path forward for me is to create Java Beans in the image of the custom data types I have now in my dmn project and import them to replace the dmn 'native' custom data types.  Now the kjar I depend on in my WS will have access to the Bean classes.